# Confused about accessing elements from IntPtr in C#

Tags: c#, kinect

I am using Kinect v2 which contains the following [CameraSpacePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx) struct:

```
public struct CameraSpacePoint : IEquatable<CameraSpacePoint>
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
}
```

The `CameraSpacePoint` also contains few methods `Equals`, `GetHashCode` etc, which are not shown above to keep the post clean and short.

Well, I define `cameraSpacePoints` in class constructor as follows:

```
IntPtr cameraSpacePoints = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(512 * 424 * 4 * 3);
```

Below is the explanation of above memory allocation:

- 512: width
- 424: height
- 4: bytes needed for single 'float'
- 3: total three variables i.e., 'X', 'Y' and 'Z'

Later, I copied values to cameraSpacePoints using [CoordinateMapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.aspx) as follows:

```
coordinateMapper.MapDepthFrameToCameraSpaceUsingIntPtr(depthFrameData,
                                                   512 * 424 * 2,
                                                   cameraSpacePoints,
                                                   512 * 424 * 4 * 3);
```

It seems perfect. Now I want to get the values from cameraSpacePoints. So I used following code inside `unsafe` block:

```
float* cameraSpacePoint = (float*)cameraSpacePoints;
for (var index = 0; index < 512 * 424; index++)
{
    float X = cameraSpacePoint[index];
    float Y = cameraSpacePoint[index + 1];
    float Z = cameraSpacePoint[index + 2];
}
```

It doesn't seem working which I realized while visualizing it. It appears to me that there is some confusion while accessing elements from cameraSapacePoints using `IntPtr`. What is missing here? Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Try replacing `index++` with `index+=3` in the for loop - seemingly you're doing 3 floats at a time. Also, as an alternative to casting to individual float*, you might cast to `CameraSpacePoint`, which will encapsulate X,Y and Z.

Comment: @StuartLC: The situation got much better and now *I am seeing three copy of same data*. In other words, I see myself thrice in the same window! LOL

Comment: @StuartLC: Surprisingly, casting trick worked. `CameraSpacePoint* cameraSpacePoint = (CameraSpacePoint*)cameraSpacePoints;` and then `X = cameraSpacePoint[index].X,` Can you please answer and explain why `float*` didn't work but  ``CameraSpacePoint*` works? Thank you very much.

Comment: @StuartLC: Also, I changed back `index+=3` to `index++`. Because now each `index` is `CameraSpacePoint`. Do you still recommend me to use `index+=3` ?

Comment: I've rolled up my comments into an answer - hopefully this clarifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your initial code, you are casting the `IntPtr` (which points to an array[] of `CameraSpacePoint`) to a raw float pointer. If you interpret the `IntPtr` as raw `float`s, since you are handling 3 points at a time (x, y and z), you'll need to increment the loop by 3 floats each time, e.g. (I've renamed variables for clarity):

```
var floats = (float*)cameraSpacePoints;
for (var index = 0; index < 512 * 424; index+=3)
{
    var x = floats[index];
    var y = floats[index + 1];
    var z = floats[index + 2];
    var myCameraSpacePoint = new CameraSpacePoint 
    {
       X = x,
       Y = y,
       Z = z
    };
   // use myCameraSpacePoint here
}
```

But that's a horribly inefficient way of handling the data, given that the data was originally a `CameraSpacePoint` in any event. Much better would just be to cast the struct directly back to the actual type:

```
var cameraSpacePoints = (CameraSpacePoint*)cameraSpacePoints;
for (var index = 0; index < 512 * 424; index++)
{
    var cameraSpacePoint = cameraSpacePoints[index];
    // Do something with cameraSpacePoint
}
```

By casting to the correct type (`CameraSpacePoint`), we're also improving the robustness of the code - e.g. if, in future, additional fields are added to a new version of `CameraSpacePoint`, then a recompile of your code against the new version will again work, whereas accessing the `float`s directly would break the encapsulation and make maintenance difficult.

The reason why we no longer need to increment the loop by 3, is because when we use the subscript / index operation on `cameraSpacePoints[index]`, is that the compiler knows to find element n at an offset of `n * sizeof(CameraSpacePoint)` after the position of the initial `cameraSpacePoints[0]`. And `sizeof(CameraSpacePoint)` is the size of 3 floats.